# Captcha Alert diplaying even I fill the captcha text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am validating the captcha with a hidden textbox, but the alert is displaying even when I fill the captcha. But on second time click it works fine as required. Might be some javascript code issue. Please see the JS code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
       $('#' + '<%=btnSend.ClientID %>').on('click', function (e) {    
       var captcha = $("input[name$=CaptchaControl1]").val();   
       $('#' + '<%=txtCaptcha.ClientID %>').val(captcha);   
   })   
});
```

Comment: when u click first time, check the hidden field value..based upon that  you track it

Comment: could you please help me with the code, as when I enter the captcha code in captcha tetbox, it should fill the hidden textbox also at the same time

Comment: IS this the way ?  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CaptchaControl1").each(function () {

                $(this).keyup(function () {
                   
                    $("#txtTotalAmt").val();
                });
            });
        });

    </script>

Answer (score 1):

You should listen for the input field onKeyUp or onChange event to copy the value of the text box into the hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var cc1 = $("#CaptchaControl1");
  cc1.keyup(function () {
    $("#txtTotalAmt").val(cc1.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: the validation doesnt goes even When I fill the captcha box. Please see the JS fiddle for your reference.
http://jsfiddle.net/nadeem/jCY7b/

Comment: any response from your side, the above code of your's does not work.

Comment: I do not use ASP and I can not run this code in jsfiddle.
Here is my working code demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/CbBv5/

Comment: ur code is working on both input type which is text, I have one captcha control and one input type text. So I want that captcha text to copy on text. Any idea ?

Comment: Try to `console.log()` or `alert()` the captcha control value. If you can get this value, then replace
    `cc1.val()`
with that value.

Comment: Its not taking the captcha value in alert. can u please console.log() procedure ?

Comment: It can be used the same as the alert for simple debugging.
Here is some example:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp

Comment: didn't helped me..:( any other way ?